# Unable to start Express Checkout - checkout with paypal in shopping cart

Tags: paypal, paypal-express

We are having a problem with how PayPal Express Checkout is functioning.  We have the "Pay with PayPal" button showing on the shopping cart.  However,when a customer clicks it redirect to paypal page only customer is not logged in but if customer is already logged in then it keeps on cart page and throw error "Unable to start Express Checkout."

I done this change :
Enable SSL verification = 'No'
but still not working for logged-in customers only.

Comment: is client requies `express checkout` ? if not you can use `standard method`....

Answer (score 1):

Try with disabling sandbox mode then it works fine.

Comment: Sandbox mode is off already.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution. You won't find trace of it in the logs, since it's not directly related with Paypal itself.

In my case, I set up some redirections based on the country of the user, so an user from European countries would be redirected to domain.com/eu if he was coming from an external domain (eg. Google). The problem is that Paypal, after the payment, would try to redirect the user to domain.com to complete the order, but my website would redirect the user to domain.com/eu, and the purchase would fail.

Your case might be different, but check that the domain from where the Express checkout starts is the same when the user comes back to the website after the payment.